# How to test/reproduce bad network behavior?

Tags: networking, testing

On Windows, I've used NEWT in the past, but it's difficult to use, not current (but I can find old copies on non-MS sites), and difficult though possible to degrade just the app's view of the network without messing up everything else on the machine like the VPN connection and NAS volumes.

On Mac, the Network Link Conditioner that is available with Xcode is far too limited and in particular doesn't model bursts, which is my current immediate interest.

I'm also interested in Windows programs running in a VMware VM, and that's already going through an emulated network connector.  I wonder if that can be made to do the traffic shaping?

In summary, can someone suggest a tool that I ought to be using for this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess http://henrydu.com/blog/how-to/simulate-a-slow-link-by-linux-bridge-123.html should work on your mac. It uses traffic control with ifconfig, something you might want to google for.